# convert exif of a photo to a lower version?

Tags: php, exif, wordpress

I am using wordpress, and I found that the `exif_read_data()` PHP function cannot read the GPS info in exif from Images with Exif Version **2.32** , but it can read from Exif Version **2.20**. 
Is there any tools for me to save the images into a lower version of Exif so my site support it?

The **PHP version** in my wordpress:**7.4.26** 
 I got the Exif version info by using ExifTool 12.54
Example Images:
Exif Version **2.32** taken by iPhone 13 pro 
https://hiketothe.top/wp-content/gallery/20230105e5a4a7e6ac96e8a792e59da1e69dbf/IMG_20230105_102126_lmc_8.4.jpg
Exif Version **2.20** taken by LG-H990 
https://hiketothe.top/wp-content/gallery/e5b9b3e5b1b1e6b288e99bb2e5b1b1/20180819_173813.jpg

-----Update------

 I used **Exif Pilot** in Windows and it can see the GPS of the image (see below pic), and , when view in **Google Photos**, it shows the location correctly. Therefore i know the photo have GPS.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the iPhone image has GPS tags? The exiftool version 12.54 does not find any.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me check if exif is accidentially removed when uploading, thanks

Comment: Have you uploaded the image again? I downloaded the iPhone image and now the same exiftool version really shows the GPS info. I am sure that in January it did not. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: yes, you are right. I am still finding the culprit of removing the exif